# Symfony Dev Toolbar not loading (wrong route)

Tags: symfony, routes, twig, symfony-2.1

I'm building a CMS style application with dynamic routing. So far it seems to work fine but the output doesn't honor the environment for WDT, assets and links... it always links to `/whatever` instead of `/app_dev.php/whatever`.

Dynamic routing is implemented via kernel.request listener. The relevant code is on [gist](https://gist.github.com/4495154). Do I need to pass the current environment to Twig at some moment?

**Edit:**

The problem appears when in DEV mode... no problem when in production mode.

Comment: Have you set up htaccess to remove the need for app_dev.php?

Comment: Why don't you create a Controller that will be responsible for the template rendering ?

Comment: @Mike I've set up htaccess to remove the need for app.php. I don't see why I should do it for app_dev.php.

Comment: @AdrienBrault What would be the benefit of it?

Comment: @Michi Maybe following MVC is interesting ? Nope ? Ok

Comment: @AdrienBrault Using a controller to listen to the kernel event would be the right way to go?

Comment: @Michi I'd have at least a controller at the end to render the template. Then, it would be better if the request is routed to the controller with the router, or you could match the controller yourself on the `kernel.controller` event. Maybe you could also use http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/routing-extra.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22509/discussion-between-michi-and-adrienbrault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AdrienBrault I finally solved the issue by using a Controller to do the rendering.

In the RequestListener I added a new route to the RouteCollection of the router indicating the controller which will handle the request.

```
$route = new Route($path, array(
             '_controller' => 'CmsBundle:Routing:routing',
        ));

$this->router->getRouteCollection()->add('cms', $route);
```

In the controller it was a bit harder to get the original URL, but finally I solved it by querying the routers RouteCollection with the name assigned in the previous add() method.